# How do I await multiple functions with completionHandlers?

Tags: objective-c, react-native, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, homekit

I'm currently working on a bridge for HomeKit for React-Native and I have to read HomeKit values to return for my Javascript code.

To read the latest value of a characteristic we must use [readValueWithCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmcharacteristic/1624188-readvaluewithcompletionhandler?language=objc) where the value isn't ready until it's complete. So I must read 6 of these characteristics and assign each one to my `NSMutableDictionary` object to return for React-Native to handle.

Rather than nesting each read inside the previous `completionHandler` with `return accObject` inside the final one, what's the cleanest approach to waiting for all `completionHandlers` to have been complete before `return`.

I've been searching for a while, looking at `semaphores`, `DispatchGroup` & a couple other solutions without a great idea about how to solve this problem.

For (rough) example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *accObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: 6];

[charac1 readValueWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
          RCTLog(@"ERROR READING HOMEKIT VALUE: %@", error);
        }
        RCTLog(@"READ SETPOINT VALUE: %@", charac1.value);
        accObject[@"charac1"] = charac1.value;
      }];
...

[charac6 readValueWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
          RCTLog(@"ERROR READING HOMEKIT VALUE: %@", error);
        }
        RCTLog(@"READ SETPOINT VALUE: %@", charac6.value);
        accObject[@"charac6"] = charac6.value;
      }];

 return accObject;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` with wait  `dispatch_semaphore_t` 
you can use this process this work for me.

```
     dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSMutableDictionary *accObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: 6];

[charac1 readValueWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
          RCTLog(@"ERROR READING HOMEKIT VALUE: %@", error);
        }
        RCTLog(@"READ SETPOINT VALUE: %@", charac1.value);
        accObject[@"charac1"] = charac1.value;
      }];
...

[charac6 readValueWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
          RCTLog(@"ERROR READING HOMEKIT VALUE: %@", error);
        }
        RCTLog(@"READ SETPOINT VALUE: %@", charac6.value);
        accObject[@"charac6"] = charac6.value;
      }];


            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
        });

         dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
 return accObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I suggest to use `dispatch_group_t` to wait for reading values and use a completion block to handle returned value.

```
- (void)readValuesWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary* values))completion {
  NSMutableDictionary *accObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: 6];

  // Initialize |charac1|, |charac2|, ...

  dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

  dispatch_group_enter(group);
  [charac1 readValueWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
      RCTLog(@"ERROR READING HOMEKIT VALUE: %@", error);
    }
    RCTLog(@"READ SETPOINT VALUE: %@", charac1.value);
    accObject[@"charac1"] = charac1.value;
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
  }];

  // ... Do same thing with another values

  dispatch_group_enter(group);
  [charac6 readValueWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
      RCTLog(@"ERROR READING HOMEKIT VALUE: %@", error);
    }
    RCTLog(@"READ SETPOINT VALUE: %@", charac6.value);
    accObject[@"charac6"] = charac6.value;
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
  }];

  dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (completion) {
      completion(accObject);
    }
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
[self readValuesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *values) {
  // Do whatever you want with |values| after reading
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I've come to a solution based on [this article](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/).

```
NSMutableDictionary *accObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: 6];
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[charac1 readValueWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
          RCTLog(@"ERROR READING HOMEKIT VALUE: %@", error);
        }
        RCTLog(@"READ SETPOINT VALUE: %@", charac1.value);
        accObject[@"charac1"] = charac1.value;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
      }];
...

dispatch_group_notify(serviceGroup,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        // Now call the final completion block
        return accObject;
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work as it won't allow the `return accObject`

Comment: It doesn't work because you need to call `dispatch_group_enter(group);` before you make the `readValueWithCompletionHandler` call, not inside the handler.

Comment: @Aris that was actually a typo and not how I had it done. There's an if statement before `readValueWithCompletionHandler` and `dispatch_group_enter` was inside of that before `readValueWithCompletionHandler`.

Comment: The problem was with the `return accObject` inside of `dispatch_group_notify`

Answer (score 0):

You can use dispatch group here, using that you cannot return a value but can call a completion block. This completion block can be there as your functions' parameters.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *accObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: 6];
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

[charac1 readValueWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        if (error) {
          RCTLog(@"ERROR READING HOMEKIT VALUE: %@", error);
        }
        RCTLog(@"READ SETPOINT VALUE: %@", charac1.value);
        accObject[@"charac1"] = charac1.value;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
      }];
...

dispatch_group_notify(serviceGroup,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        // Now here instead of returning a value, you can call a completion handler.
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, this function is being used to convert the HomeKit service to a dictionary so I need to return said object when all the values have been read. How can I achieve that in the final completion handler?